# How to programmatically create a query string limiting records for Oracle using SQL Alchemy?

Tags: oracle, sqlalchemy

Given a SQL Alchemy engine, schema name, table name, and limited number of records to return; I want to generate a query string that can be used in the database that was given in the engine.

If I construct my sqlalchemy query the same way in all cases like this:

```
import sqlalchemy

limit=10
schema='schema_name'
table='table_name'

raw_query = (
    sqlalchemy.select([sqlalchemy.text("*")])
    .select_from(
        sqlalchemy.schema.Table(
            table, sqlalchemy.MetaData(), schema=schema
        )
    )
    .limit(limit)
)
```

I can successfully compile this query to a string form using SQL Alchemy compile for Snowflake like this:

```
snow_engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('snowflake://{user}:{password}@{account}/'))

query = str(
    raw_query.compile(
        snow_engine, compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True}
    )
)

print(query)

> SELECT * 
FROM schema_name.table_name
 LIMIT 10
```

When I try the same for Oracle though, I lose the schema and table names:

```
oracle_engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/?service_name={service_name}')

query = str(
    raw_query.compile(
        oracle_engine, compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True}
    )
)

print(query)

> SELECT  FROM DUAL 
WHERE ROWNUM <= 10
```

I can get it working using a special case for Oracle like this:

```
raw_query = (
    sqlalchemy.select([sqlalchemy.text("*")])
    .select_from(
        sqlalchemy.schema.Table(
            table, sqlalchemy.MetaData(), schema=schema
        )
    )
)

query = str(
    raw_query.compile(
        snow_engine, compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True}
    )
)

query += "\nWHERE ROWNUM <= {limit}".format(limit=limit)
print(query)

> SELECT * 
FROM schema_name.table_name
WHERE ROWNUM <= 10
```

but is there not a more implicit way to do this?

Edit: I was running SQL Alchemy 1.3.8. It looks like this problem was solved in 1.4.

Comment: I can reproduce  your result with `DUAL` without understanding the cause. Anyway see the *workaroud* in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for my in `SQLAlchemy-1.4.3` for Oracle

```
raw_query = (
    sqlalchemy.select('*',table(table_name, schema=schema_name)).limit(limit)
)
```

The produced SQL Statement is

```
SELECT anon_1.*
FROM (SELECT *
FROM schema_name.table_name) anon_1
WHERE ROWNUM <= 10
```

which is exact what is expected for [`LIMIT` in Oracle dialect](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/oracle.html?highlight=limit#limit-offset-support)